# MockMvc and losing @SessionScope bean value

Tags: java, spring, mockito, session-scope

I have a `@SessionScope` bean that keeps track of the current users role.  When I run the application the value is present, however when I run my integration tests the bean is null.

Here's what I have:

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public UserSessionDataImpl implements UserSessionData {
   private String role;  // "Admin" or "User"
   // getters/setters below
}
```

// Service

```
@Service("roleService")
public RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {
   @Autowired
   UserSessionData sessionData;

   public String getRole(){
      return this.sessionData.getRole();
   }
   public String setRole(String role){
      return this.sessionData.setRole(role);
   }
}
```

// API

```
@Api
public class TicketApi {
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;
    @Autowired
    private TicketService TicketService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "person/{id}/tickets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTickets(long personId) {
        // only admins can lookup tickets
        if(roleService.getRoles.equals("Admin"){
           // do logic
        }
    }
}
```

// Unit test method

```
@Before
public void setup(){
   roleService.setRole("Admin");  //set role to admin for testing
}

@Test
// Calls TicketApi
public void getTicketsTest(){
   mockMvc.perform(
         get("/person/{id}/tickets"));  // blows up due to null role
}
```

I am stumped as to why my `roleSerivce` loses the reference to `sessionData`.  I do see that `UserSessionDataImpl` does get instantiated multiple times, which I wouldn't think would happen.  I'm wondering if the mockMvc call creates a new Session which would cause the extra instantiations.  Has anyone else figured this issue out?

Comment: I'll try implementing using an already existing `MockHttpSession` like in the link below

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/05/testing-spring-session-scope.html

Comment: This did not work for me...  back to square one.